# Error in MODIFY TABLE clause in ABAP code

Tags: abap

Error at modify table clause. What is wrong here.
I suspect it has something to do with having a unique key- colb.

```
DATA : BEGIN OF line1,
   cola TYPE i,
   colb TYPE i,
   END OF line1.
DATA mytable1 LIKE HASHED TABLE OF line1 WITH UNIQUE KEY colb.

DO 4 TIMES.
   line1-cola = sy-index.
   line1-colb = sy-index ** 2.
   INSERT line1 INTO TABLE mytable1.
ENDDO.

line1-colb = 80.
**MODIFY TABLE mytable1 FROM line1 TRANSPORTING colb
where (colb > 2) and (cola < 5).**

LOOP AT mytable1 INTO line1.
   WRITE :/ line1-cola, line1-colb.
ENDLOOP.

Error:
".", "ASSIGNING <fs>", "REFERENCE INTO data-reference", or "ASSIGNING            
<fs> CASTING" expected after "COLB".            

Note: Error line is in bold. The error is shown in red.
```

Comment: What is the error message you're getting, and what part of it don't you understand? It should be pretty obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@vwegert is right, you can't change the key values in HASHED and SORTED tables. On the other hand your error is syntactical. If you change:

```
MODIFY TABLE mytable1 FROM line1 TRANSPORTING colb where colb > 2 and cola < 5.
```

For

```
MODIFY mytable1 FROM line1 TRANSPORTING colb where colb > 2 and cola < 5. "'TABLE' word omitted
```

It is also a syntactical error, however, SAP will show you the error more clearly:

> You cannot change the search key using "MODIFY". "COLB" is contained
>   in the table key of "MYTABLE1".

Check the [documentation](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_erp60_sp/helpdata/en/fc/eb35eb358411d1829f0000e829fbfe/content.htm). When specifying a condition (or including a 'WHERE') in 'MODIFY' statement you should not use the word 'TABLE'.

If you still want to modify the key field then change the internal table as 'STANDARD' like this:

```
DATA mytable1 LIKE STANDARD TABLE OF line1 WITH KEY colb.
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This has been in the [documentation](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_45b/helpdata/en/34/8e72f96df74873e10000009b38f9b8/content.htm) for a very long time:

> You may not use a key field as a TRANSPORTING field with HASHED or
>   SORTED tables.

Comment: I changed my code to : MODIFY TABLE mytable1 FROM line1 TRANSPORTING cola
where (colb > 2) and (cola < 5). however, the error persists.